# Make separator div same height as maximal neighbour div height

Tags: html, css

How with help of css and html i could do this:
i have 3 div's, and i have separator between them, and this separator, and text-area div must be not 65px as in my example, but maximal height div (in example this is first div), for example if there i have 2 lines only, i will have smaller by height div, and separator must be same height (maximal). How could i do this... didn't have any ideas(

http://jsfiddle.net/crjsg/

```
<div class="introtext-text-area">
                <div class="introtext-separator"></div>
                <div class="introtext">
                  here is example text of test example with 3 <br>lines
                </div>
                <div class="introtext-separator">some text</div>
                <div class="introtext"></div>
                <div class="introtext-separator"></div>
                <div class="introtext"></div>
              </div>
```

css:

```
.introtext-text-area {
height: 65px;
width: 690px;
margin: 8px 0 0 0;
}

.introtext-separator {
width: 3px;
height: 65px;
float: left;
border: none;
background-color: red;
margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
}

.introtext {
width: 211px;
height: 58px;
float: left;
padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
border: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: left;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #c2c2c2;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

how could i set automatical height for text-block and separator, and this height must be same for 3 text div's and it's separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use display:table and borders :

```
<div class="introtext-text-area">
  <div class="introtext">
    here is example text of test
    example
  </div>
  <div class="introtext">
    some text
  </div>
    <div class="introtext">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.introtext-text-area {
  display:table;
  border-right:solid red;
}
.introtext {
  width: 211px;
  padding:5px;
  display:table-cell;
  border-left:solid red;
}
```

Comment: ie6 - 7 support table> ?

Comment: do you ? else use the faux column technique to draw your borders : http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns

Comment: i mean table cell etc in css, not html table design ie7 didn't support it http://htmlbook.ru/css/table-layout

Answer (score 0):

Use these css defintions:

```
.introtext-text-area {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
}
.introtext-separator {
  float: left;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
  height: 100%;
}
.introtext {
  width: 211px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #c2c2c2;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.bordered {
  border-left: 3px;
  border-left-color: red;
  border-left-style: solid;
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

Add the handy .bordered class to each of your divs:

```
 <div class="introtext-separator bordered"></div>
 <div class="introtext bordered">
```

The trick is that the parent div has overflow:hidden and the bordered class has really large paddings.

[Forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxVj4/)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to put in the separator. In your example you had text in it. My guess is that you don't need a separator at all, so I would go for @GCyrillus solution since it's much cleaner.

Comment: @in separator is 1px width pixel line, no text! a little mistake in SO

Comment: i use updated browsers, even - i don't use IE at all, but i think about other user's, and crossbrowser mean this, ie too, 6 is realy a dino, but 7th is often used in our country(    but for such speak, i will not accept you answer... be kindly, and not so rude)  by table i mean css table layout - table cell etc...   ahahaha, you comment was deleted up ) )))